# Php pagination based on values in column

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I hope this question isn't a dup. I've been looking at pagnation with php but what I've seen is based on the total number of entries and a fixed amount of records on each page. How can I use pagination based on the values that appear in a particular column?

So for example `SELECT answers, name FROM table`

Lets say there are 5 `answers` to choose from and I want to use pagnation for each `answer`.
Not all the answers have the same amount of records allocated to them.

This would obviously just return 5 pages of similar amount records:

```
$per_page = 5; 
$sql = "SELECT answer, name FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
$pages = ceil($count/$per_page)

//Pagination Numbers
for($i=1; $i<=$pages; $i++)
{
echo '<li id="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</li>';
}
```

Comment: I would like to use pagination based on the values that appear in a particular column not just based on the total records and the amount of records selected per page.

Comment: Care to give an example?

Comment: Well thats why Im asking cause Im not sure. Ive looked through a few tutorials but they all seem have a set amount of records per page.

Comment: Are you saying you want each 'answer' to have it's own page?

Comment: Alright ill give you an example and you tell me if im on the mark. You have a table with one column called 'items' this table has three rows. In the items column the numbers go 2, 6, 7. You want to paginate the data in this table, using the 'item' in the selected row? (This is all hypothetical)

Comment: @MitchS Yes and each answer has a varying amount of records associated with it.

Comment: Then have one page per answer and select the associated records for the current answer (for the page you are on). The SQL used for the pagination doesn't have to be the same as the content you are displaying.

Comment: get link from this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044647/displaying-results-hyperlink-numbers-like-a-search-engine/13044809#13044809) for pagination

Comment: @F4r-20 there are a certain amount of items to choose from and pagination is based on these items. Each item is a different page.

Comment: @Dark_Wish not quite what Im after.